# ServiceStack namespace change not working

Tags: c#, web-services, mono, namespaces, servicestack

Small Problem, When I run my ServiceStack API application on my windows machine the namespaces appear correctly as i state them to be. But when i run the service on a Linux machine off mod_mono. Then those namespaces gets overridden by something else. Please see my code below:

DTO

```
namespace API_ESERVICES_NOTIFICATION
{
[DataContract(Namespace = "urn:com.example:service:20130308")]
public class GetAccountNotification
{
    [DataMember]
    public GetAccountResponseTO getAccountResponse {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
}
```

Windows Generated SOAP11 xml

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetAccountNotification xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:com.example:service:20130308">
          <getAccountResponse xmlns:d2p1="urn:com.example:service:entity:20130308">
```

Linux Mod_Mono

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetAccountNotification xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/API_ESERVICES_NOTIFICATION">
          <getAccountResponse xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/API_ESERVICES_NOTIFICATION.Model">
```

Now how do i get the Linux Namespace to be urn:com.example:service:entity:20130308 and urn:com.example:service:20130308, and not http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/API_ESERVICES_NOTIFICATION.Model. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Mono not picking up the DataContract's namespace or not considering `urn:` prefix a valid xml namespace. I recommend [filing a bug in Mono](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/).

An alternative you can try is leaving the namespace empty and specifying an assembly attribute in your project's `Assembly.cs` instead, e.g:

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("urn:com.example:service:20130308", 
  ClrNamespace = "API_ESERVICES_NOTIFICATION")]
```

Comment: I tried this, Unfortunately it doesn't work, I will submit a bug but unfortunately we will never get the new mono release on Linux. The support for only goes up to 2.10.8 which is already behind the current release. Does serviceStack support System.xml.serialization? as an alternative?

Comment: No, ServiceStack doesn't have its own XML Serializer, it just uses the DataContractSerializer under the hood. You can swap it out by registering your own in `IAppHost.ContentTypeFilters`, but you'd have to find one that works well in Mono.

Comment: Solved this issue by replacing the system.runtime.serialization with teh wcf RMP from this site http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=mono%28System.Runtime.Serialization%29